# What is the best way to represent a stateless property that can be overridden?

Tags: java, oop, programming-languages, overriding

I have an abstract class that implements some feature, let's say `FileFormat`.  For each file format I want to support, I have a subclass, such as `ZipFileFormat` or `TextFileFormat`.  Some features of a file format are stateful, such as an operation to translate the file into a stream of text.  But some other features have no state, such as the default file extension, or the magic pattern prefix for the file's contents.

One way to represent this would be to have an abstract method that can be overridden to provide the property:

```
abstract String getDefaultExtension();

...

String getDefaultExtension() { return "txt"; }
```

This works, but there is no way to express the base class's assumptions about this property.  In this case, a client of the `FileFormat` API would like to assume that the return value of `getDefaultExtension()` never changes over time.  But with an override, there is no way to declare this intent in a subclass or assert the restriction in the base class.

An alternative is to use a member variable.  In that case the value of a format's default extension would be passed to the base class constructor.  But this is not great in that it will take up storage space in every instantiation of our class -- in the case of a file extension, all instances will have the same extension.

Another way to go is a `Properties` object type solution where you have a structure hold a bag of settings, which could be static or not, but that loses type safety, and API documentation, etc.

Any other options or comments?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Java at least, it won't actually take up additional space if you store it as a field of the class.

Say you have

```
String fileExtension="txt";
```

Instead of having each instance of the class store the `txt` `String`, Java will simply have them refer back to the original copy.

You could also do

```
static final String fileExtension = "txt";
```

That would make the field universal across all instances of the class, and unable to be changed (in Java Strings are immutable.  When I refer to 'changing' a String, I do not mean changing the individual characters within the string.  Rather that `fileExtension="bfr";` would make `fileExtension` point to a NEW `String` object, with the `bfr` value assigned to it).

Comment: Yes, I could make a static final member for the property, but those of course are not overridable, so I would then have to pass that to the constructor or use it in an overridden method.  So that would fix the issue of non-shared data.  Each subclass would have to implement this idiom, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Is a proliferation of short strings really that critical?

That aside, there's no great way to specify immutability-over-time outside of the class itself other than as a comment.

You could use a `static final` constant and return that in the getter to avoid the repetitive data. Use `@see` in the Javadocs to make the constant and the getter refer to each other.

Don't know if that's any better than the getter with a literal, other than minor semantics.

You could have each subclass register itself with its extension, I suppose.

You can always use a custom doclet to expose additional information in Javadocs. I also don't really believe relying solely on Javadocs is necessarily the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do both: the base class will have default implementation that returns value of field initialized in constructor. The subclass *can* override the getter and add its own logic. I think that the issue of memory required for storing of string `"txt"` for each instance of class is irrelevant: you have to store it anyway even if it is hard coded in subclass. And I personally do not care about 6 additional bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid mixing stateless and stateful code. My suggestion is to split the implementation into two parallel trees of classes. One contains the static metadata (like the file extensions) and the other contains worker objects that are configured with the metadata.

That would give you a `ZipFileType` singleton which you use in all instances of `ZipFileFormat`.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the solution I've been leaning toward.  A little more work, but it would have the right amount of expressiveness.

Comment: Depending on other impl. details, the static parallel classes could be the factory class or similar.

Comment: Or the meta data can be used in the factory to build the implementation.